# node js pointing to the test database instead of specified database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend

this is my code. this supposed to enter data in Demo database but it keeps inserting data in test database. I am not getting where I am making mistake.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const main = async()=>{
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://Demo:Demo@localhost:27017/?authMechanism=DEFAULT&authSource=Demo",{useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name : String,
        brand: String,
        price : Number
    });

    const ProductsModel = mongoose.model('demoProducts',ProductSchema)
    let data = new ProductsModel({name:"volvo",brand:"tata",price:18000});
    let result = await data.save()
    console.log(result);

}
main()
```

Comment: Do you select the Demo database anywhere? If not, try putting in in the connection string.